# Why am I getting a segmentation fault (core dumped)?

Tags: mysql, c

This is the code I am trying to run. It compiles fine, and worked great until yesterday.

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

  MYSQL *conn;
  MYSQL_RES *result;
  MYSQL_ROW row;
  int num_fields;
  int i;

  conn = mysql_init(NULL);
  mysql_real_connect(conn, "hostname", "username", "password", "database_name", 0, NULL, 0);

  mysql_query(conn, "SELECT * FROM tabletest");
  result = mysql_store_result(conn);

  num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);

  while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))
  {
      for(i = 0; i < num_fields; i++)
      {
          printf("%s ", row[i] ? row[i] : "NULL");
      }
      printf("\n");
  }

  mysql_free_result(result);
  mysql_close(conn);

}
```

Note that the parameters for `mysql_real_connect()` are generic here for privacy, but like I said, it worked yesterday. When I try to run the code after compiling successfully, I get:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: "It worked yesterday" is not a good excuse for "I don't check the results of my mysql API calls".  Add error checking, and narrow your search to the offending function call.

Comment: is that the full error trace?

Comment: @paddy I don't know how to check that. And how do I narrow my search, I don't have any more information except for that one line upon running. Thanks.

Comment: @IonutHulub Yes, nothing else at all.

Comment: @AdrianCornish How can I find that? All that comes up when I run the code is the segmentation fault. I get nothing when compiling.

Comment: haven't used sql with c++ so this might be crap advice but it looks like your trying to store the results at a memory location for which you haven't allocated any memory at this line `result = mysql_store_result(conn);`. is that the way it's supposed to be?

Comment: If you are using linux run `gdb <myprogram> <corefile>` and then just type `where` at the gdb prompt

Comment: You assume that every call to the MySQL API has succeeded, then you go ahead and use the results.  If the API documentation tells you what will be returned in case of error, you should check for that error because otherwise you are most likely going to segfault when you access invalid or uninitialised memory.  Aborting with the message "connect failed" or "query failed" will go a long way in figuring out what *is* working and what *isn't*.

Comment: @IonutHulub mysql API takes care of memory - you must free it though

Comment: @paddy You're right, I'm error checking now, and things are making more sense. Terrible mistake on my part. Thanks.

Comment: if you find out what went wrong you can answer your own question so ppl that have the same problem in the future can see the solution.

Comment: @IonutHulub Yep, did so.

Answer (score 4):

Paddy pointed out the key problem, I didn't error check. After error checking, I found out that I wasn't being granted access to my remote server and was getting

```
Error 1045: Access denied for user 'username'@'ip' (using password: YES)
```

I then realized that the IP address of my computer changed after turning it on. I never knew this happened. So I had to go back into cPanel, and add my 'new' IP address to the remote access list for MySQL, and it works. Now the issue is to find out how my IP address can stay static.

The moral of the story is to always handle errors.